# yii2 rest api tuning

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I'm trying to get list of all items in json format, using REST api of yii2. Basically, it returns a list of 20 items with no sort. But I need all items with some sort. If I had to show them, I could maybe redefine action index of controller in such way:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
    $dictionaries =  $modelClass::find()->select([
            '{{site_search_dictionary}}.*', // select all customer fields
            'COUNT(*) AS dd' // calculate orders count
        ])
        ->joinWith('queries') // ensure table junction
        ->groupBy('dictionary_id') // group the result to ensure aggregation function works
            ->orderBy('dictionary')->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dictionaries' => $dictionaries,
    ]);
}
```

But what can I do to change response in same way for rest query?

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `prepareDataProvider` for index action.

```
public function actions()
        {
            $actions = parent::actions();
            $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'prepareDataProvider'];

            return $actions;
        }
```

This will call `prepareDataProvider` method from your controller instead of built-in.

For example:

```
public function prepareDataProvider()
        {
            $searchModel = new SiteDictionarySearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
            return $dataProvider;
        }
```

And you should make Search model for your model for such needs. To return all items better use `ArrayDataProvider` with `find()->asArray()`

Here is how return should look like:

```
return new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $rows,
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => count($rows),
                ],
            ]);
```

Comment: Yes, but why I need to use ArrayDataProvider if I want the result to be formatted as json?

Comment: You can return activeDataProvider instead, but will get problems with pagination limit then. Look at the source code of IndexAction in rest.

Comment: Ok, good, now it works fine, but seems that find()->asArray() is not necessary here - cause the result of find->select... is already an array.

Comment: It depends on situation. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it lick this

```
public function actionIndex()
{
$modelClass = $this->modelClass;
$dictionaries =  $modelClass::find()->select([
        '{{site_search_dictionary}}.*', // select all customer fields
        'COUNT(*) AS dd' // calculate orders count
    ])
    ->joinWith('queries') // ensure table junction
    ->groupBy('dictionary_id') // group the result to ensure aggregation function works
        ->orderBy(['dictionary_id'=>SORT_ASC])->all();

return $this->render('index', [
    'dictionaries' => $dictionaries,
]);
}
```

Comment: No, it has no result. I think maybe redefining  prepareDataProvider can help, but I don't know what I should return in that case.

Comment: what you mean by redefine prepareDataprovider?. where is the data provider?,